# Replace XML value through javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this XML code on my .ASPX page

```
<XmlDefinition>
 <View BaseViewID="1">
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='AccountID' />
                <Value Type='Text'>1</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"></FieldRef>
        <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"></FieldRef>   
        <FieldRef Name="Modified"></FieldRef>   
        <FieldRef Name="Editor"></FieldRef>       
        <FieldRef Name="Company"></FieldRef>
        <FieldRef Name="Category1"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
```

But the '1' has to be replaced by a value i have in my javascript file, connected to this .ASPX page. How can i manage that, is there a way to set a variable or something?

These are the only techniques i can work with, because i am building a SharePoint-Hosted app, but that is not the main problem!

In forward, many thanks!

Comment: Certainly you can change this by using DOM parser in JavaScript

Comment: Can you give an example, i really don't know how to do this..?!